# How to split a text file by a given separator in c#

Tags: c#, split

I'm having a trouble with a program. I got to read a file `*.txt` and split it by a given character, for example: the file contains this :

```
rotbrow
yabector
gamerue
```

So when I insert the given separator that is `a`, it should separate the lines like this:

```
rotbrow
ya
bector
ga
merue
```

but it prints them like this without the a :

```
rotbrow
ya
bector
ga
merue
```

This is the code I am using :

```
foreach (string line in  File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\ArchivoaSeparar.txt"))
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(cadenaTextBox.Text.ToCharArray());

    foreach (string item in parts)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

I don't understad why dont show the given separator (the a in the las example) and I have to to do this with any text entered and a given separator.

Hope that you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not get the delimater as part of return value after the split operation.
you can have extra logic to add that as below:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\ArchivoaSeparar.txt"))
            {
                String checkItem = cadenaTextBox.Text.ToString();
                string[] parts = line.Split(checkItem.ToCharArray());

                foreach (string item in parts)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add((line.Contains(checkItem) ? item + checkItem : item));
                }
            }
```

Comment: this worked bro but why is adding the item to the last line , for example i charge a File that contains Hola (hello in english) it separates de string but the delimater is appering at the end of the line,¿Does is for the ((line.Contains(checkItem) ? item + checkItem : item)); that every time the foreach executes add the delimater to the last line

Answer (score 2):

When you split a string on some separater, that separator is *not* part of the resulting parts. If you want to see that "a", you need to add it back in manually (on every part execpt the last).

By the way: that `ToCharArray` will not have the effect you probably want: if you enter "or" as separator, then both "r" and "o" are independent separator, so they split whether or not they are together (the string would split on a single "o" and split double on "ro" or "or".)

Comment: Yes that is what i was thinking to do but didnt know how to add the delimater ,the answer below this one do it but always add to the last line and is happening as you say that if i input a separator or i should display "or" and the rest of the split text.